If the conducting wire isn't isolated (connected to battery)
It is said that if a conducting wire is isolated charges will redistribute itself on the surface of the conductor i.e no internal $E$.

what if the conducting wire is connected to a DC battery (do electrons still distribute themselves on the surface only?)

Do we define relaxation time for isolated conductors only?



Yes, if you wait long enough for everything to "settle", even when connected to a battery there will be no volumetric charge density in the bulk. Charge imbalances are distributed solely on the surface of the conductor. These surface charges are responsible for establishing the uniform field in the conductor. You may find this paper by Chabay and Sherwood to be helpful (in particular section II D has a helpful figure).
If you are willing to start with the fact that the $\mathbf{E}$-field is uniform, then you can also use that to easily see that there cannot be any volumetric charge density. Gauss's law tells us the volumetric charge density is proportional to the divergence of the $\mathbf{E}$-field: $$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}$$
but the divergence of a uniform vector field is zero: $$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=0\implies\rho=0$$
No, the relaxation time does not only apply to isolated conductors. Really, the utility of the relaxation time comes from informing you about the natural timescale for the transients of the system (like the charges rearranging themselves) - something that is generally most useful precisely when the conductor is not isolated.


It is said that if a conducting wire is isolated charges will redistribute itself on the surface of the conductor i.e no internal $\vec{E}$.

The $\vec{E}$ field inside of a conductor will be $0$ if there is no current in the conductor. This is a consequence of the microscopic version of Ohm's Law.
$\vec{J}=\sigma\vec{E}$
where $\vec{J}$ is the current density at a given point, $\sigma$ is the conductivity of the material, and $\vec{E}$ is the electric field intensity. If there is no current, i.e. $\vec{J}=0$, then either the conductivity is $0$, (--it would not be a conductor if conductivity is $0$ --) or the $\vec{E}$ field is $0$.
If one wire of a battery is connected to a conductor, then (unless there is more to the story that isn't mentioned) no current will flow through the conductor. It takes two connections to the battery to make a complete circuit. So with one wire connected, there will be no $\vec{E}$ field within the conductor. With two wires connected, there will be an $\vec{E}$ field.

what if the conducting wire is connected to a DC battery (do electrons still distribute themselves on the surface only?)

Even if there is current in a conductor, and $\vec{E}\ne0$, in steady state, the net charge density within the conductor (assuming it is uniform) is 0. The only places where there can a net charge density in steady state is at the interfaces between the conductor and something else (for example, an insulator, or a conductor with a different conductivity).
This is a consequence that follows from the continuity equation:
$\nabla \cdot \vec{J} + \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = 0$
(where $\rho$ is charge density), together with the microscopic version of Ohm's Law,
$\vec{J} = \sigma\vec{E}$
and Gauss's Law:
$\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$
where $\epsilon_0$ is permittivity.
Thus, the continuity equation
$\nabla \cdot \vec{J} + \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = 0$
becomes
$\nabla \cdot \vec{J} = 0$
The microscopic version of Ohm's law says
$\vec{J} = \sigma\vec{E}$
so
$\nabla \cdot \sigma \vec{E} = 0$
Expanding we get
$(\nabla\sigma)\cdot\vec{E} + \sigma(\nabla\cdot\vec{E})=0$
Wherever $\nabla\sigma=\vec{0}$, we have
$\nabla\cdot\vec{E}=0$
But from Gauss's Law
$\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$
where $\rho$ is the charge density.
So, wherever $\nabla\sigma=\vec{0}$, we have the charge density must be $0$ i.e.
$\rho=0$
If we assume that the conductor is uniform, the only places where $\nabla\sigma \ne \vec{0}$ are on the surfaces of the conductor.

Do we define relaxation time for isolated conductors only?

No, the conductor does not need to be isolated. Current may flow within the conductor and the charges still experience relaxation.
If the current is constantly changing, there may be some net charge density within the conductor. However, this will be small. The relaxation time in conductors such as copper are so short in relationship to the rate of change of current typically seen in electronic circuits, that this rate of change is "essentially $0$" at the time scale of relaxation.
